# Issue Between Ultrasonic sensor and ethernet shield Arduino

Tags: c++, ethernet, arduino-uno

I have a project that is connecting ultrasonic sensors into Arduino Uno and the Arduino code is taking the readings from the sensors and send them to a remote server throughout ethernet shield,

Now the problem I am facing is that I need to use 6 ultrasonic sensors but when the Arduino is taking the reading from more than 4 sensors the Arduino do not function properly, but if I made the reading of the two rest sensors from pins located for one of the previous sensors it works fine, or even if I assign a default value for those two sensors it works fine,

The problem I am facing is related to the following pins: 
10, 11, 12, 13 
That the ethernet shield is using them but how can I overcome this problem and run all the six sensors ?

You can find part of the code below:

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#define ECHOPIN1A1 3        // Pin to receive echo pulse 
#define TRIGPIN1A1 2        // Pin to send trigger pulse
#define ECHOPIN1A2 5        // Pin to receive echo pulse 
#define TRIGPIN1A2 4        // Pin to send trigger pulse
#define ECHOPIN1A3 7        // Pin to receive echo pulse 
#define TRIGPIN1A3 6        // Pin to send trigger pulse
#define ECHOPIN1B1 9        // Pin to receive echo pulse 
#define TRIGPIN1B1 8        // Pin to send trigger pulse
#define ECHOPIN1B2 5        // Pin to receive echo pulse 
#define TRIGPIN1B2 4        // Pin to send trigger pulse
#define ECHOPIN1B3 3        // Pin to receive echo pulse 
#define TRIGPIN1B3 2        // Pin to send trigger pulse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a board with more GPIO pins like the Arduino MEGA. Or you could connect together the trigger pins and use only one Arduino pin to drive them all.

**Edit:**
Make sure you read Tansir's comment below and experiment to see what works and what doesn't. With the number of available pins, you would need to trigger 3 ultrasonic sensors per pin (2 pins for triggering + 6 pins for reading the echo).

There is another solution: You could use multiplexers/demultiplexers to drive up to 8 sensors with 5 pins (2 data pins and 3 address ones). This would add to the complexity of the hardware, however.

Comment: You need to be careful triggering multiple ultrasonic sensors at once.  Depending how their aimed you'll get multiple returns per sensor fouling up your measurements due to interference and multipath echoes.  It's safer to trigger them sequentially with a small delay between each OR make sure they're aimed in opposite directions to minimize interference.

Comment: That what I aimed for triggering them sequentially but the problem I think is the limitations of input and output since I need to use 6 ultrasonic sensors, I am thinking to trigger 3 sensors from a shared pin for triggering and get the reading sequentially at each sensor of those three I want to read I will trigger the three sensor from the shared pin and then I will get the reading from the specific sensor I want to read,